# Remove and rearrange in arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` and I was going to use the `java.util.ArrayList.remove()` method in android but my question is if you have an `ArrayList` which has the values at the following indexes, then remove at index, will the others be bumped up an index? Here an easier way to understand what I am trying to ask:

```
Starting Arraylist:
------------------------
|   Index   |   Value  |   
------------------------
|    0      |    "a"   |
|    1      |    "b"   |
|    2      |    "c"   |
|    3      |    "d"   |
|    4      |    "e"   |
------------------------
```

Then I remove at index 3 will the new array be array A or array B

```
Arraylist A:                Arraylist B:
------------------------    ------------------------
|   Index   |   Value  |    |   Index   |   Value  |   
------------------------    ------------------------
|    0      |    "a"   |    |    0      |    "a"   |
|    1      |    "b"   |    |    1      |    "b"   |
|    2      |    "c"   |    |    2      |    "c"   |
|    3      |          |    |    3      |    "e"   |
|    4      |    "e"   |    ------------------------
------------------------
```

Comment: Why didn't you just try? Surely, would've taken less time than posting it here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will be **B**, If you modify an arraylist using index operations, `ArrayList` will be rearranged as you have understood. Thats why `ArrayLists` are costly if there are too many modifications

This is what `remove(int)` documentation says

> Removes the element at the specified position in this list. Shifts any
>   subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their indices).

Answer (score 0):

Your ArrayList will be like your **B** example.

That's exactly how ArrayList works, they are rearranging.

Answer (score 0):

If you want anything like that nobody bumps into your remove position, try inserting a null object at that position, it would hold the position for that purpose.

In fact a better solution is to create a dummy object, which is kind of your version of a java null object. But this dummy object will give you flexibility to add some functionality to support your logics and program flow.