# Iterating arraylist and removing in java

Tags: java, arrays

What happens when I remove some middle elements in an arraylist? Will it automatically re-arrange the whole array list? For example consider the below case

```
list.add(one);    /** has index 0 ***/
list.add(two);    /** has index 1 ***/
list.add(three);  /** has index 2 ***/
```

If I remove the second element having index 1, then what is the index of the object having "three". is that arraylist automatically rearranged, the whole list and its indexes, when size of the array list is big?

Comment: Just try it and figure out, no?

Comment: Short answer is "Yes"...but you should run your own tests to see.

Comment: in my case is array list is very big. and thankyou

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove and rearrange in arraylist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18714352/remove-and-rearrange-in-arraylist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29)

```
Removes the element at the specified position in this list. 
Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their indices).
```

Answer (score 0):

From the source of the ArrayList

```
 public E remove(int index) {
    RangeCheck(index);

    modCount++;
    E oldValue = elementData[index];

    int numMoved = size - index - 1;
    if (numMoved > 0)
        System.arraycopy(elementData, index+1, elementData, index,
                 numMoved);
    elementData[--size] = null; // Let gc do its work

    return oldValue;
    }
```

As can be seen its creating a copy. Hence yes indexes will be updated

Answer (score 0):

If you modify an arraylist using index operations, ArrayList will be rearranged as you have understood. Thats why ArrayLists are costly if there are too many modifications

This is what remove(int) documentation says

```
Removes the element at the specified position in this list. Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their indices).
```